# How can I approach the Error that has been shown very shortly while my Ubuntu is starting up?

Tags: 13.10, error-handling

I would much appreciate your help with this one. At the moment Im using Ubuntu 13.10 and I have Lenovo G585 laptop, not jet a year old. But... There is this Error that has been appearing for a very long time, something about blacklight not find, and it shows up with every start. How can I get to the Command line (or something else), do tell, to see what exactly is the text of that error? And is there a way to know what is this about, software or hardware? Tnx

Comment: You could try openning a termminal window (ctrl-alt-t), then copy/pase something like `dmesg | grep backlight`, and hit Enter.

Comment: Thanks! I've got this :  [   15.441435] [drm:radeon_acpi_init] *ERROR* Cannot find a backlight controller

Comment: Great! Now you just google `"[drm:radeon_acpi_init] ERROR Cannot find a backlight controller"`, including the quotes, and read what others had to say.

Comment: I did google it, but I do not have the same problem as described there. My screen turns on right after that message is displayed, and their screen remains black. + no one fixed it yet.

Comment: So, do you experience any problems or inconveniences because of the error? If it's purely cosmetic, then you might just leave it be. Anyway, we'll need some hardware specs, so it would be helpful if you could add the output of `lspci -nn` to the question. Please use http://pastebin.com if you can't edit the question.

Comment: The problem is that my laptop generally acts like it's 15 or so years old - it tends to freeze for a few seconds every now and then, browsing the Web using Firefox is a pain as it is really slow and prone to freezes as well (even though the Internet connection is quite good - no such problems on my PC), playing any games even on lowest detail settings (besides solitaire and Mahjongg) is beyond its capabilities, even including flash games on the Internet, and so on. First I suspected the Ubuntu installation, now I wonder if it could be a hardware issue.

Comment: Here is the output of lspci:
http://pastebin.com/jVceJE6E

Comment: You probably just need to install the AMD driver: http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Saucy#Install_Latest_Nvidia.2FATI_drivers. It's proprietary, and therefore is not included by default.

Comment: Thank you. I did not answer earlier cause my Lenovo kinda die. Hard disk. Service changed it, and it works better now. But I have to say the error about backlight is still here, and I decided to just leave it be, as you previously proposed.

Comment: Welcome back, and thanks for the update. Have you installed an AMD driver? Did it help improve the laptop performance?

Comment: No did not get around to do it before the hard disk broke and it died :) it was in a repair service for two months and now I have a new hard disk and THAT did improved  it's performance. Turns out it was faulty from the start. But like I've said, the error is still shown, just the way I described it here before, and since it seems that it had nothing to do with the bad performance, I decided to do nothing, but I might do it when I have the time.